# Realm random crash observed "Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL) in tid 28688 (RealmFinalizing), pid 28451"

Tags: android, realm

App crashes randomly sometimes with following message

```
Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL) in tid 28688 (RealmFinalizing), pid 28451
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to issue github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/6093 this should be fixed in realm release 6.0.1